# multi tenant shared database with common data between tenants

Tags: database, shared, multi-tenant

I have a multi tenant application with a single database with all records containing a TenantId.  There are, however, situations where we want to have common data for all tenants to benefit from.  We are actually rebuilding an old ASP( noir, not clasic ) app and in that app they have a TenantId =1 where all the common stuff goes.  This seems kind of hacky to me as you end up with queries that say where TenantId=342 || tenantId=1.
Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks,

Raif

Comment: You could have a PrivacyClass field with values of "private" if it's data private to a tenant, or "universal" if all should see it. Then query on `TenantId=342 || PrivacyClass="universal"`.

Comment: Thanks for that input.  I guess I was hoping there was some other way then filtering but I've decided go the route of a "company tenant" or whatever to store the common data in.  I'm surprised there weren't more responses this must be a fairly common problem.

Comment: This is in fact still a problem in 2013, can't seem to find any decent solutions. Our case involves tenants with private data, public data, and data shared with specific collaborators. Do let me know if you have found good solutions to this.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you can achieve this by having the tenant I'd column value as null for thee record that you want to have as global or shared across the different tenants. In case you need to store the tenant specific value, just store the value in a row with the tenant I'd value SRT in the tenant I'd column. In this way, you can have both the tenant specific and global value reside in a single table with ease of retrieval.

Post your understanding if further discussion may be required.

Answer (score 0):

A few approaches are mentioned here, including Johnathan M's suggestion of a "private" field.  Have been looking into the issue myself, and it looks like row security may be a solution.  For example, [with Postgres](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Row-security).